# Automapping using open generics and including the source in a ForMember statement

Tags: generics, automapper, open-generics, automapper-5

I've recently upgraded from Automapper 4.2.1 to 5.1.1 and am having issues with a previously valid mapping involving open generics.

Previously, within the automapper configuration, I had the following  open generic mapping configuration

```cs
CreateMap(typeof(IPager<>), typeof(ModelPager<>))
    .ForMember("Items", e => e.MapFrom(o => (IEnumerable) o));
```

This works in Automapper 4 but fails in 5 with a `InvalidOperaionException` when attempting to map via `IMapper.Map<TDestination>(source)`. It appears to fail when executing the mapping of the *Items* `ForMember` operation with an exception message of "*Sequence contains no matching element*"

As reflected in the example implementation code below
`IPager<TSource>` implements `IEnumerable<TSource>`, and the `Items` property of `ModelPager<TDestination>` is an `IEnumerable<TDestination>` so the cast should be valid. and there exist a valid mapping for each `TSource` to `TDestination`

```cs
CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
```

**IPager** interface

```cs
public interface IPager<out TItem> : IEnumerable<TItem>
{
    int CurrentPage { get; }

    int PageCount { get; }

    int PageSize { get; }

    int TotalItems { get; }
}
```

**IPager** implementation

```cs
public class Pager<TItem> : IPager<TItem>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<TItem> _items;

    public Pager(IEnumerable<TItem> items,
                 int currentPage,
                 int pageSize,
                 int totalItems)
    {
        /// ... logic ... 
        this._items = items ?? Enumerable.Empty<TItem>();
        this.CurrentPage = currentPage;
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.TotalItems = totalItems;
    }

    public int CurrentPage { get; }

    public int PageCount => (this.TotalItems + this.PageSize - 1) / this.PageSize;

    public int PageSize { get; }

    public int TotalItems { get; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator() => this._items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

**ModelPager**

```cs
public class ModelPager<TItem>
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get; set; }

    public int PageCount { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
}
```

What is the proper way to map this in Automapper 5 without either abandoning [open generics](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics) by explicitly mapping each possible mapping, or by using a custom open generic [type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) that would require me to manually map all properties and use reflection to resolve the open types for assignment?

Comment: This looks like a bug, can you open a GitHub issue?

Comment: @JimmyBogard can do

Comment: Issue [#1624](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1624) has been submitted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this looks to be a bug ([AutoMapper #1624](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1624)), a work around can be done with a custom open generic `TypeConverter` that **does not** require reflection.

The mapping should be changed to something along the lines of

```cs
CreateMap(typeof(IPager<>), typeof(ModelPager<>))
    .ConvertUsing(typeof(PagerToModelPagerConverter<,>));
```

with a custom `ITypeConverter`

```cs
public class PagerToModelPagerConverter<TSource, TDestination> : ITypeConverter<IPager<TSource>, ModelPager<TDestination>>
{
    public ModelPager<TDestination> Convert(IPager<TSource> source,
                                            ModelPager<TDestination> destination,
                                            ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var list = source.ToList(); // avoid redundant iterations
        var itemMapping = context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(list);

        var modelPager = new ModelPager<TDestination>
                         {
                             CurrentPage = source.CurrentPage,
                             Items = itemMapping,
                             PageCount = source.PageCount,
                             PageSize = source.PageSize,
                             TotalItems = source.TotalItems
                         };

        return modelPager;
    }
```